# How to store server TOKEN and use it on my 2nd activity webview?

Tags: java, android, json, authentication, token

Hi im stuck with how to store server TOKEN to the Shared Preferences and use it on 2nd activity, anyone help?

```
 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String myResponse = response.body().string();
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                                    System.out.println(obj.getString("status"));
                                    System.out.println(obj.getString("status_desc"));
                                    System.out.println(obj.getString("login_token"));
                                    if (obj.optString("status").equals("Y")) {
                                         class Preferences {
                                            public void setAccessToken(@NonNull Context context, String token) {
                                                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                                editor.putString(obj.optString("login_token"), token);
                                                editor.apply(); }
                                            }
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("AccessToken", (obj.getString("login_token")));
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                                .setTitle("WARNING!")
                                                .setMessage((obj.getString("status_desc")))
                                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                                                .show();
                                    }
                                }
```

these my coding on 1st activity

```
class Preferences {
                                        public void setAccessToken(@NonNull Context context, String token) {
                                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                            editor.putString(obj.optString("login_token"), token);
                                            editor.apply(); }
                                        }
```

tried this, but didnt found any token stored on my shared preferences.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the "obj.optString("login_token")" with a simple string like `"token"` and it should work fine.

For example:

To save `editor.putString("token", token).apply()`

To get the token `sharedPreferences.getString("token")`

Comment: no working on next activity T^T

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the token? I don't see where the sharedPreferences can be wrong. You can println to the logcat or show a toast with it for testing purposes.